# nginx permanent redirect rule from one domain to another with URL params

Tags: nginx, redirection

I am redirecting the URL from one domain to another using the nginx server block like below:

```
server {
        server_name subdomain.example.com
        return 301 https://subdomain.example2.com$request_uri;
        }
```

Now I need to do the same redirection by capturing the URL params as below:
https://subdomain.example.com/some-unique-strings/xy000012345 should be permanently redirected to https://subdomain.example2.com/ab/string?stringid=12345
Need to capture the digits after xy0000 dynamically and pass it to new URL as stringid=(captured digits)

Answer (score 0):

`rewrite` and `return` statements are executed in order. You can place a specific `rewrite` statement before the general `return` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    rewrite ^/some-unique-strings/xy0000(.*)$ https://subdomain.example2.com/ab/string?stringid=$1 permanent;
    return 301 https://subdomain.example2.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Richard. I have tested this but this still returns the old URL which is request_uri, as it is. This is not rewriting the URL as I want.